# Induced homeomorphism on spectra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

It is not true that rings with homeomorphic spectra are isomorphic; take any two nonisomorphic fields. It is also an exercise in Atiyah-Macdonald that the induced map on spectra is dense if and only if the kernel is contained in the nilradical of the source.

When is it true that a ring homomorphism $f:A \rightarrow B$ induces a *homeomorphism* $f^{*}:\mathrm{Spec} B \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec} A$ given by $f^{*}(\mathfrak{p}) = f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$?